# (Yet Another) Answer that is worded slightly differently

Tags: discussion

I am consulting the wisdom of the Meta.

In the discussion ([RMagick complains it was configured with a different version of ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2887342/2061684)), it seems that there is more than one way to solve the issue (mostly because of the use of packages and modules which simplify commands).

A mod and I were in disagreement (no animosity from my side, just curiosity, that's why I'm asking the question).

I had received the answer in question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185784/2061684) within the "Late Answers" queue.  After investigating the question, while the late answer was similar to others, it was not directly a copy/paste.  So I edited it for formatting and let it go.  It seems that was the wrong answer.

In this context, running `bundle` is the same as running `bundle update rmagick` is the same as running `gem install rmagick`.

There are many "shortcut" commands which run longer commands in development languages.  **Are later-posed similar answers which use shortcuts considered delete worthy?**

If that's the case, every other answer on that thread should be flagged.  The way I saw it, was a new user potentially did not understand the difference between a shortcut command or a full command and posted their answer.

**Should I have adjudicated that differently?**  Also, it seems my edit was inappropriate due to some back-end rule system, **was my format edit harmful?**

(Update: During the course of this, the answer was deleted.  Although, I still would like know what I did wrong for future editing purposes.)

Comment: it is not a new idea or concept, because the same is already written before, and how many tom,es can you say unistall it and reinstall it with the correct version. But i also understand your misgivings, because of he many declined flags

Comment: Yes, but as meta says "an answer is an answer, however partial or incorrect" (paraphrase). So why was it deleted, why was editing bad?

Comment: no, only today i flagged an answer, because it was a duplicate, as i only can for this purpose use a moderator flag and explained it shortly. The answer was deleted. But as i said, sometimes i get declined, that is part of SO life

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I wasn't accusing you, I was hoping you had insight.  I appreciate your responses.

Comment: :D basically nobody can gove you an answer, every moderator has his guidelines, but is free to interpret them and everybody has good and bad and and some large between days. So before you flag an answer, think twoce about are there really really fits with the suggested föags, and when you have the feeling that warants a mod flag, then do it, . when you are unsure downvote it simply and go on

Comment: Worded differently here seems to mean slightly different syntax of the code. Question is if it's obvious or not. If not, it might still have rather been an edit to an existing answer.

Comment: While it looks like one, that "answer" is not an answer. It is the canonical "Thank you" Not-An-Answer, as evidenced by the fact that it ended with `thx @Skotti`, where Skotti is the author of the **accepted answer**. And FWIW, the moderator that deleted the answer is - I believe - not a subject expert on Ruby, but a subject expert on Not-An-Answers.

Comment: I think I was in on this. I cannot see the post nor the conversation anymore, but if I recall correctly, the post specified a user that it thanked. Which prompted me to go and look at that particular post, seeing that it had copied parts of it. Then it proceeded to use "bundle" which was covered in the comments on that post and in other posts, which led me to believe they also copied that and had just slipped to include multiple users to thank. It read as a clear "Thank you" post to me.

Comment: Under the impression it's a "Thank you" post, I found editing the post obscures that fact, which is why I replied to you regarding the edit. Removing the post in the Low Quality Post queue / by moderator is much easier for everyone.

Comment: Editing out the "Thanks" part seems a good edit to me. Whether the better solution was to get it deleted, I can't say as don't know much about the subject. But I do see two other "not deleted" answers that are 100% identical. Why this one had to be deleted while the two other are allowed to stay, seems a bit strange to me.

Comment: @4386427 If we were to not remove a "Thank you" post because other Answer are similar, there's a lot of cleanup that wouldn't even be possible. We can only remove content that doesn't bring value when we see it. I do not have 20K delete vote privileges and so I cannot delete vote those Answers. I can only try to ensure this one is removed.

Comment: @4386427 That question, and its other answers, are at least 4 years old. Policy regarding answers, particularly on old questions, has become much stricter since then.

Comment: @Scratte yes, you were in on that, I didn't want to name you or make it a "me vs you" thing, that's why I didn't tag you. To me, (pre-edit with thank you), it read as a "thanks for putting me on the right path". I can see from the general sentiment and upvotes that I was in the wrong, which is why I was looking for feedback.  I am honestly just looking for feedback, and I appreciate replies from everyone.

Comment: @jnovack I never considered our interactions as a "you versus me" :) No need to worry about that. Even if you had mentioned me in this post, I would not have been pinged. I just happened upon it by chance and felt I should at least elaborate a little. I guess I didn't lie when I said I would read your meta post ;)

Answer (score 11):

With a bit of investigation of the post, a non-expert (such as myself) can deduce that this was not an answer because it is thanking another post.

[image]

The first hint is that the poster thanks a specific user which posted the accepted answer. The first line is basically included in the accepted answer. The second line is copied from another answer to the question. Moreover, the second answer explains how the second line is an alternative to the second line Skotti posted.

**Edit:**

It may initially appear that `bundle` is substantially different than `bundle install`. However, the former is actually a [poorly documented](https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/issues/1452) omission of the default `install` command. This might be appropriate as a comment, but not as an answer.

Therefore, the appropriate review action was flag as Not an Answer.

Sometimes it takes a little effort to investigate a review, and I know I've made the wrong call on more than one occasion.

Comment: Awesome work on the free hand red circles :)

Comment: @Scratte it looks like a Treasure map. ... ;)

Comment: And what about rollback? Does it means that mod rollback edit to make it again *perfect* NAA? Anyway, I wouldn't dare posting *thoughts* as an answer, that should Martijn Pieters♦ do.

Comment: "The second line is copied from another answer to the question" Hmm... not a 100% copy... for someone without knowledge of "bundle" it can be read as two different approaches, i.e. "bundle install" versus "bundle". At least to me, it isn't clear that this the same answer.

Comment: "Therefore, the appropriate review action was flag as Not an Answer." I doubt that very much. It is very rare that the appropriate action is to flag as NAA. NAA flags are declined for all but the most obvious of cases. The fact that you had to use images and draw lines (very nice free hand red lines ;)) should be indicative of its eventual declination. In this specific case, it might have been deemed helpful only because of its eventual deletion.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think about 2/3 of all my flags have been "Not an Answer" flags, so for me it's not very rare. "Thank you" posts are covered by those. I took the meaning from [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)

Comment: @Scratte Then you've had better luck than others. There's a reason [we have a tag just for \[not-an-answer\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/not-an-answer), after all.

Comment: First time seeing I was amazed by red lines across multiple images in a post. Oh, never mind.

Answer (score 2):

I have no knowledge about the subject. So when I look at

**Answer 1 (constructed by commands from two answers)**

```
sudo gem uninstall rmagick
bundle install
```

and **Answer 2 (the now deleted answer)**

```
gem uninstall rmagick
bundle
```

I don't see 2 identical answers. The second answer tells me that `bundle` (apparently) can do the same for me as `bundle install`. So I learned something from the second answer.

Therefore I considered it a mistake to delete the second answer while it was IMO correct to do the (now rolled-back) edit to remove the "Thanks" part.

Comment: I noticed the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887342/rmagick-complains-it-was-configured-with-a-different-version-of-imagemagick#comment18143906_7771801) on the Answer that was explicitly thanked mentioning "bundle" without "install". But maybe I'm just splitting hair now.

Comment: @Scratte Well... I also heard the phrase "Comments are not answers"

Comment: I'll give you that many people don't know that `sudo` doesn't change the answer (sudo is the [command you use to execute things with administrative privileges](https://xkcd.com/149/) in Unix environments). Still, it's good to learn that one either way.